# EF Core 2.1 Props inside where cause null reference

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

When I migrated from EF 1.1 to 2.1 I started getting null reference error when iterating inside where condition, it seems like StatusCashAdvanceList is not loaded at the time where is executed.

CashAdvance.cs:

`public virtual ICollection<StatusCashAdvance> StatusCashAdvanceList { get; set; }`

**Stack Trace:**

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
lambda_method(Closure , CashAdvance)
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNext()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities<TOut, TIn>(IEnumerable<TOut> results, QueryContext queryContext, IList<EntityTrackingInfo> entityTrackingInfos, IList<Func<TIn, object>> entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor<T>+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
[------].CashAdvanceController.Index() in CashAdvanceController.cs
+
            var cashAdvances= _context.CashAdvance
```

**Null reference:**

```
var cashAdvances = _context.CashAdvance
                .Include(a => a.StatusCashAdvanceList)
                    .ThenInclude(s => s.ObjTypeStatusCashAdvance)
                .Where(a => a.ActualStatusCashAdvance.IdTypeStatusCashAdvance < PAYED)                
                .ToList();
```

**This is the props method used inside Where**

```
 public StatusCashAdvance ActualStatusCashAdvance{
   get {
       if(this.StatusAdiantamentoList.Count == 0)
           return null;               
       var status =  this.StatusCashAdvanceList
                         .OrderByDescending(a=> a.Data).First();
           return status;
       }               
}
```

**This works, but I think it's just a workaround:**

```
    var cashAdvances = _context.CashAdvance
        .Include(a => a.StatusCashAdvanceList)
            .ThenInclude(s => s.ObjTypeStatusCashAdvance)
        .Tolist()
        .Where(a => a.ActualStatusCashAdvance.IdTypeStatusCashAdvance < 
        PAYED)                
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Does the error have a stack trace that you can post?

Comment: Yeah, client side filter evaluation is unstable and doesn't play well with navigation properties. Try avoiding it by not using unmapped properties inside `Where` (and in general).

Comment: @RichieThomas here is the stack trace

Comment: @IvanStoev I will highly consider your suggestion, but the current system is already using client side filter evaluation since EF Core 1.1 so I am trying something with less impact before covering the system with unit tests and making changes